# While driving 96 Jeep cherokee stalled

Tags: jeep, cherokee, classic

Jeep it completely died out. I changed the crankshaft sensor not issue. Come to find out the 30 amp fuse behind battery keeps blowing and not gettting power to coil? Tries to start but won't battery is charged turn key on fuse blows

Answer (score 1):

Fuses are there to protect from runaway electrical currents that can damage components or start a fire, if you have a fuse repeatedly blowing then there's a short in your electrical system. A wire has gotten stripped and is touching ground (your car's frame is ground) or a component has failed internally and is allowing a run-away current.

If the fuse blows when you turn your key to *start* then the problem is in the starter system somewhere and it's relatively simple to resolve by checking the wiring for bare spots, changing the starter motor, voltage regulator all depending on what you find.

If the fuse blows when you turn the key to position 2, where you power up the car's systems and then the main fuse blows then that's an odd issue, you'd need to work to isolate which system is causing the short and fix it. Replacing sensors or mechanical parts is not going to resolve it.